# По какому принципу образуется порядок элементов в unordered_map?

Tags: c++, unordered-map

Само название структуры подразумевает, что элементы в ней не отсортированы, но если перезапускать все время программу и выводить циклом элементы, то они всегда будут в одном порядке.

Например вот код из [этой](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/178712049X) книги

```
struct coord {
 int x;
 int y;
};

bool operator==(const coord &l, const coord &r)
{
 return l.x == r.x && l.y == r.y;
}

namespace std
{
template <>
struct hash<coord>
{
 using argument_type = coord;
 using result_type = size_t;
result_type operator()(const argument_type &c) const
 {
 return static_cast<result_type>(c.x)
 + static_cast<result_type>(c.y);
 }
};
}

int main()
{
 std::unordered_map<coord, int> m {{{0, 0}, 1}, {{0, 1}, 2},
 {{2, 1}, 3}};
 for (const auto & [key, value] : m) {
 std::cout << "{(" << key.x << ", " << key.y
 << "): " << value << "} ";
 }
 std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Хэш формируется из сложения `x` и `y`, поэтому я думал, что по итоговому хэшу и будет выстроен порядок, но оказалось, что это так не работает.

Порядок вывода всегда такой:

```
{(0, 1) : 2}
{(2, 1) : 3}
{(0, 0) : 1}
```

Как это работает?

Comment: Это *не сортировка*, но порядок связан с хеш-значением. Причем опять же - это не значит, что элементы отсортированы по хешу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того, что бы ответить на вышеуказанный вопрос, для начала нужно понять, а как собственно устроен `unordered_map` изнутри. Есть два способа реализации, но самый простой и легкий из них - метод цепочек. Вроде он и применяется в стандартной библиотеке.

Сами данные хранятся в векторе списков. То есть так

```
class my_umap {
  std::vector<std::list<node_type>>> m_data;
};
```

когда нужно вставить элемент, то от индекса рассчитывается хеш (в нашем случае функция хеша должна уметь преобразовывать тип ключа в некое число в диапазоне `0..m_data.size()-1`. Обычно, хеш функция просто возвращает обычный `int`, а потом используется деление по модулю с помощью `%`. По полученному числу находится элемент вектора, в который в список и добавляется необходимый элемент (да, предварительно, проверяется, а нет ли такого элемента ещё).

Функция итерации по мапе обычно делается по простому - проходимся по всем элементам массива (вектора) и выводим элементы списка (опять же, в естественном порядке).

Теперь стает понятно, что при выводе элементов порядок будет определятся хеш функцией и тем, как элементы были вставлены в пределах одного и того же значения хеш функции.

Хеш функции обычно такие, что одному и тому же значению входного значения соответствует одно и тоже выходное значение (иначе это все работать не будет).  Но с другой стороны, хеш функция старается максимально равномерно "размазать" значения хеша. Поэтому, если два значения (например, два `int`) упорядочены по возрастанию, то значения хеш функции (идеальной конечно) будет упорядочены с вероятностью 50 на 50 (да, они могут совпасть, поэтому, наверно на самом деле это будет 49-49-2 или что то другое, похожее).

Чем же определяется хеш? его может явно задать программист, а может использоваться реализация от компилятора. Важно то, что с большущей вероятностью (если код не менялся), она не поменяется, а значит, значения хеша, которые определяют элемент вектора, будут те же.

Рекомендую попробовать написать свою реализацию `unordered_map` (того, что я написал выше уже достаточно для этого) и все вопросы пропадут сами собой.

Некоторые языки (например, golang) любят рандомизировать немного хеш функцию от запуска к запуску (для мнимой безопасности), тем самым доставляя кучу приятных впечатлений для молодых программистов.

Есть ещё одна реализация unordered_map  - [открытая адресация](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A5%D0%B5%D1%88-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0), но он немного сложнее, как по мне в реализции.

Answer (score 2):

То, что они не отсортированы, не означает, что порядок должен быть случайным. Он всегда определяется конкретной реализацией этого контейнера. Главное не рассчитывать на то, что если в контейнере лежит определенный набор элементов, то его порядок будет одним и тем же. Вполне логично, что в примере из книги одна и та же последовательность операций приводит к одному и тому же результату. Однако если с контейнером до или после произвести какие-нибудь еще действия, не меняющие в итоге содержимого контейнера (например добавить, а за тем удалить элементы, или вызвать reserve), то его содержимое может запросто оказаться в совершенно ином порядке.

```
{(2, 1): 3} {(0, 1): 2} {(0, 0): 1} 
{(0, 0): 1} {(0, 1): 2} {(2, 1): 3} // c `m.reserve(1);` перед for
```

[online compiler](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlJvoCqAZ0wAFAB4gA5AAYppAFZdSrZrVDIApACYAQjt2kR7ZATx1KmWugDCqVgFcAtrRAA2UlfQAZPLUwAcs4ARpjEINycpAAOqEKE5rR2ji7uMXEJdL7%2BQU6h4ZFGmCZmdAwEzMQEyc6uHsaYponllQTZgSFhEVFCFVU1qfV9bX4deV2RAJRGqA7EyBxSmjIAgjoAzH7IjlgA1JrrNua9xJjMTgfYy2vam7TbDnsHNg60JFin6AD6TszRl9cTg5TLs0O99gB2fSrXZ%2BAi7cQHaErWH0XYATyR100EIAIljVtdgqh7LtUNEwswiMQDvj1riIGhaL1QSTiOh9to3KxSKzmfCwezOW5iJNsVDrrtTgQ5rRdqwAHTifb02lSpXCnRueUK9Equm49WY9bInH4wmrWjnTBCaLMBa7XrocXIgiYJzRVRulU2AGrIEghDMIQIZ6C53rK6EiUwhzxdS7SrAZxWAhfAjoin61nvAkouN%2BYBSm0OVhpjNZtXxABemHTedOQlL5czmDJFOIVJIEEmjLoLKTKfo6dbwuQkz5vUlOORxZlxDlvSpeGQXxYU8OjebI4pl0ZSrFMIMjoqZlX64Izy3ZZ3mD3yF1YpN07x4rpptfFpWcN2vz8PZdSVdmAmcgOA8CT3QEAQFed4wkwb5fn%2BQ5w15OFLl/SF9AlKEZF5GQzV5ThCKwmc8N2Yi8V5bQSNAqFtCIkj1jNFjnxhCDwJoYhdj7flEwcIhhX2ABWXQAGtMHRXkADc2AcO9hMNEBfwnUD2I4yDoLQASfWeTkaKhCAdG0XTDl2CT0Q1Z49OM3ljNMmxzMk3UwI46yzOMyZlPs9zHNkxw218/SzWCtiUQ0yFzXCjSnS02Z4SCsAlmEmxaCSvMIJY9TSOyiDYpgt52XgxC/jDNl0DQ%2BgMKcUicN0ciCKoijaLq8jKNxaiWuw3QGOaprmNfV8woi38FUbMJpMwCBOCfWcIq4nimQHATUCEzRRIsmS5IUpSVJy6KOPy7SEsOGztAM3QjPOhynMs5Ugts/SboslzcvAh7zq8p6gv8%2BSbuMkKAeGiKsoOvKCCglB4pu9KUrSpZgZAz81jxKRplYaRhPkVxZHkVBpF9PRjyEWZ5kC25OHkAhpDkSZpjEkBhLwjGpG4bGabx6R5CEEA8Op3HpjgWAkEwcRGhWsgKAgJMhFENRigYBBUAAdxxynSDQD08C9RI5f8VhFZVnG5A11AtfYcJgE4a3TfNsIAHkBMN1WOc8MXkBWYhgB5qR5FFxpynwHH5H4RgWHYLheFD4QxEkXHFGUVR1BQAwDBUPBgh5yBpnJUpmS5mY5gWZQnT8PWFaVl2pHV5XO2iaRKfRzH2fj/GpHEAAONwAFo3G4XZgGQZAKM4BVOF2bB3YlnjcEIEhOXWGbdkJ/Q9Cpjm6dIBmmZUaQ2dIY3Od9oxedIfnaabqRtBbk22/XgXpkm4h4gsbggA%3D)